# How do I get Tegaki to work as a keyboard input on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to get handwriting to work in some degree where if Ubuntu is given an input of a Chinese character, it will display and write as that character.

IMEs (ibus/FCItx/SCIM..etc) to my understanding largely use pin-yin to are main source to write Chinese characters.

For now, I'm trying to get Tegaki (https://tegaki.github.io/), which is a handwriting application in Ubuntu to function as a keyboard input so that Ubuntu will be expecting to output of Chinese characters instead of having the IME trying to interpret the input.

My current problem is that when Ubuntu is given the Chinese character directly, it will not display.

For Example,

If the user types A on the keyboard. 
A --> IME translates the character to  --> A // and therefore the letter is typed

More conceptually, 
If you type "→" (imagine you had a button on your keyboard that had that as a button) which is a unicode character i think, the IME can recognize this character and will output the same "→"

"→"  --> IME translates the character to "→"

My problem is when Ubuntu receives the input of "↦" for example, which is another Unicode character, it does not output anything.

"↦" --> IME dosn't know what it is--> outputs ""

That would lead me to believe that that character is missing from the gnome character map.

Similarly, when Ubuntu receives the input of "中" it outputs ""

I'm just trying to get proof of concept to see if direct inputs in Chinese will actually work via Tegaki for example.

Questions are
1)How do I get Tegaki to work as a keyboard input on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

2) Is there a better approach to troubleshoot my problem?

3) Is my problem really just missing font/IME or some combination of the two?

Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

Install fcitx and then the japanese input system mozc. one of mozc tools settings is for handwriting, it uses tegaki.